# Como instalar plugins no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Como instalar plugins para aumentar as funções do Android Studio?

O Android Studio é uma ferramenta ótima que realmente ajuda a diminuir o tempo criando apps, porém eu gostaria de aumentar mais minha produtividade adicionando plugins que automatização tarefas. Afinal, os computadores vieram pra isso, certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem duas formas básicas de se adicionar um plugin no Android Studio. Primeiramente, você pode baixar de duas formas:

- Baixar um plugin em zip pelo GitHub ou do site da [JetBrains](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio)
- Baixar diretamente pelas configurações do Android Studio

Em ambas as formas, você precisa instalar pelo mesmo lugar. No Android Studio vá em:

1. Preferences...
2. Plugins
3. Click em **Install JetBrains plugin** ou **Browser Repositories** (no que preferir)
4. Procure pelo Plugin
5. Click em Install
6. Reinicio o Android Studio para ativar o plugin

Caso você tenha baixado um plugin pelo github ou outro site, basta clicar em **Install plugin from disk** no passo 3 e seguir os passos restantes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]