# Como importar um drawable automaticamente em várias dimensões no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Como eu poderia adicionar uma imagem (drawable) em várias dimensões de uma vez, já criando as versões de alta densidade de pixels?

- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi
- xxxhdpi

Teria alguma forma de agilizar essa tarefa?

Comment: Para quem atualizou o Android Studio para a versão 3.6.1 pode ter causado algum conflito. Sugiro baixar e instalar o plugin:
https://github.com/Vincent-Loi/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um plugin muito valioso que realmente ajuda a agilizar essa tarefa. Se chama **Android Drawable Importer**.

Basicamente ele faz a mesma coisa que Adicionar um ícone usando o Vector Asset no Android Studio por exemplo, já criando versões de suporte para dispositivos de telas grandes, por ex.: xxhdpi ou 2k.

## Instalação

Para fazer a instalação, pesquise por **Android Drawable Importer** na seção de plugins, nas preferencias do Android Studio.

Qualquer dúvida, siga esse post do StackOverflow:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277662/94862

### Como Usar

Depois de instalado, para usar basta fazer o seguinte:

1. Na aba Project, click do lado direito.
2. Va para New e escolha Batch Drawable Import
3. Clique no + e adicione uma imagem em alta resolução (preferencialmente acima de 4000px)
4. Em Source selecione xxxhdpi caso sua imagem seja de alta resolução. Ou selecione os critérios que ela com o qual ela bate.
5. Após terminar de fazer as configurações, clique em OK e espere o Gradle terminar de trabalhar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]